# Solving simple dice roll and getting result in mean

Tags: r

what im trying to solve is simulation of dice roll and it goes as follows:

- numbers are default for dice 1,2,3,4,5,6 and it follows probability distribution of {0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1}
- set.seed is 555
- there will be 100 rolls
- result should be in mean from numbers that were given

Here is what i did:

```
set.seed(555)
sample(1:6, size = 100, prob = c(0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1), replace = TRUE)
#and previous one gives me result of 
[1] 5 2 1 4 1 3 6 5 3 2 2 5 4 4 6 1 4 3 1 6 5 3 5 5 3 4 3 6 5 3 4 5 1 5 5 5 3 5 1 5 2 4 1 1 3 3
[47] 2 3 3 3 4 3 1 3 4 5 4 5 6 2 4 3 5 3 1 2 4 4 5 1 4 3 5 1 1 2 5 1 3 5 6 6 6 2 2 2 5 4 3 1 1 5
[93] 1 6 5 2 6 5 3 1
```

Now issue is what i have is that i dont understand how can you get mean out of this number or what function to use. I know that rnorm and mean are used but i do not understand how.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value (i.e. the mean of an infinite number of throws) will just be:

```r
sum(1:6 * c(0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1))
# [1] 3.45
```

If you want to do it as a simulation of 100 rolls you can do this:

```
set.seed(555)
sample1 <- sample(1:6, size = 100, prob = c(0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1), replace = TRUE)
```

Now you can examine the sample and take its mean:

```
sample1
#  [1] 5 2 1 4 1 3 6 5 3 2 2 5 4 4 6 1 4 3 1 6 5 3 5 5 3 4 3 6 5 3 4 5 1 5 5 5 3 5 1 5
# [41] 2 4 1 1 3 3 2 3 3 3 4 3 1 3 4 5 4 5 6 2 4 3 5 3 1 2 4 4 5 1 4 3 5 1 1 2 5 1 3 5
# [81] 6 6 6 2 2 2 5 4 3 1 1 5 1 6 5 2 6 5 3 1
mean(sample1)
# [1] 3.45
```

If you want to get really fancy, you can simulate your 100 dice throws thousands of times and plot the results, all with a single line of code:

```r
 hist(sapply(1:1000, function(x) mean(sample(1:6, size = 100, prob = c(0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1), replace = TRUE))), main = "Means of 100 throws (n = 1000)", xlab = "mean")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you can use, including both empirical mean and theoretical mean

```
set.seed(555)
p <- c(0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.1)
res <- sample(1:6, size = 100, prob = p, replace = TRUE)
# empirical mean
mean_empirical <- mean(res)
# theoretical mean
mean_theoretical <- seq(6)%*%t(t(p))
```

**Additional**

- If you want to view the distribution of mean values of 100 rolls, you can repeat the event (mean of rolling dice 100 times) by many times, e.g., 100000 times, then you can try the following code (using `replicate`)

```
r <- replicate(100000,mean(sample(1:6, size = 100, prob = p, replace = TRUE)))
barplot(prop.table(table(r)))
```

[image]
- If you want to view the empirical distribution of `res`, you can use the following line (using `prop.table()` + `table()`)

```
barplot(prop.table(table(res)))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Tell me though, why with 100000 replicates the empirical distribution is so far from the given probabilities?

Comment: @AllanCameron the first one is "distribution of mean", which follows the central limit theorem so it looks like a Gaussian distribution, while the second is just the "distribution of rolling dice once"

Comment: Thanks. I got what the graphs were (stats background), but in your code `res` is overwritten by the 100000 replicates, so I was expecting the second graph to be a near-perfect match to the distribution. Now I understand - you were plotting the first `res` before it was overwritten with the replicates. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes. Actually my first one is the same as your figure, but I used `replicate` to do that while you used `sapply()`

Comment: I haven't used `replicate` before - certainly neater than `sapply` here. The `barplot` is also nicer than the standard histogram. Nice to be learning new basics after many years in R! Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for reply and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jyry you are welcome! does this answer your question?